# Local functions calling each other

Tags: function, recursion, lua, local

I have two functions that occasionally call each other, and they are local to a module that uses them to build another function. The module is somewhat similar to this piece of code:

```
local function iseven(n)
    if n == 1 then
        return false
    else
        return isodd(n - 1)
    end
end

local function isodd(n)
    if n == 1 then
        return true
    else
        return iseven(n - 1)
    end
end

local evenOrOdd = function(n)
    return iseven(n) and "Even" or "Odd"
end

return evenOrOdd
```

The problem is, when calling `evenOrOdd` from another file I get the error `attempt to call global 'isodd' (a nil value)`.

I noticed that this doesn't happen if I set `iseven` to global, but I would like to keep them local to my module.

I even tried putting a dummy function declaration (`local function isodd() end`) before the line where `iseven` is declared. I also tried inserting just `local isodd` in the place of the dummy function declaration, but in both ways it doesn't work and I get different kind of errors.

I know this is because Lua has closures and when `iseven` is declared it catches the actual value of `isodd`, which is either `nil` or the dummy function, and modifying it after doesn't count, but is there a way to bypass this?

Comment: Example of forward declaration in Lua: `local f; local function g() return f() end; function f() return g() end`

Comment: @Egor Skriptunoff oh right. As I said in the question, I tried it. But it seems I forgot to delete `local` before `function isodd(n)` and I got the `attempt to call upvalue 'isodd' (a nil value)` error. Thanks.

Comment: The error message for the code you gave should be `attempt to call global 'isodd' (a nil value)`, which should explain what happened.

Comment: Be careful about carrying the concept of "forward declaration" over from other languages. There is no requirement have an "actual declaration" later. In Lua, only local variables (including parameters) are declared. A function is a value created at runtime from a function definition when an expression containing it executed.Such a value is often assigned to a variable. (The `function ()` syntax is shorthand.)  Again, functions are not declared.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the call to `isodd` in `iseven` uses a *global* variable, not the local one defined later.

Use forward declarations, as suggested by @Egor:

```
local iseven, isodd

function iseven(n)
...
end

function isodd(n)
...
end

...
```

Comment: I don't get it. Is the problem that isodd doesn't exist yet at the point where iseven is executed, and the compiler therefore defaults to a global isodd that doesn't exist? So global functions can be later in the code but global ones can't?

Answer (score 2):

Another way to get past this problem is to use tables. Plain local variables are probably more efficient, but with tables you dont need to manage the declarations.

```
local T = {}

local function evenOrOdd(n)
    return T.iseven(n) and "Even" or "Odd"
end

function T.iseven(n)
    -- code
end
```

The gist of this is that because the table is defined at the top, everything below it has access to it and you can dynamically change it's contents.
When `evenOrOdd` is called, `T.iseven` should already be defined by then even though it was not defined when `evenOrOdd` was defined.

Answer (score -1):

Better check for `num%2` - remainder of the division

Comment: It was just an example to show how my functions work. They are really too long to copy them here and the question can be answered anyway (see in the comments).