# Scope Problems in Lua

Tags: lua, scope, null

Why do I get the error "*attempt to call a nil value*"? It doesn't tell me why or where, which must mean it can't find the Dummy function. But I forward declared it, so it should see it.

```
local Dummy

local function Start()
  print("this line is printed")
  ErrorReport(Dummy)
  print("this line is printed")
end

local function Dummy()
  print("this line is not printed")
end

function ErrorReport(...)
  print("this line is printed")
  local ok, error = pcall(...)
  if not ok then print("Error: "..error) end
end

Start()
```

Comment: I fixed that error in the answer you received for your last question.

Answer (score 1):

`local function Dummy` defines a second local variable named `Dummy` that shadows the first one, which remains with value nil.

Just do `function Dummy () ... end` instead, which is equivalent to `Dummy = function () ... end`.

Comment: This was explained in the answers and comments to your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71102432/why-cant-this-be-local

Comment: So when I forward declare stuff, I have to not declare the actual later implementation of the function local again? That doesn't make it global, right?

Comment: See my edited answer

Comment: Thanks, that answer in the other thread was only added/edited a few minutes ago, and I didn't see it. Previously it showed the upvalue function _with_ a local declaration.

Comment: @JohnBig, Consider deleting this question if it is answered in the previous one

Comment: Thanks, I'll delete it. So for instance by saying `local a = 5` `local a = 6` I would not change the 5 to a 6, I would create another "shadowing" a?

Comment: Every `local` statement creates *new* local variables.

Comment: How can it shadow if it has the same scope? Then the first `a` just becomes obsolete somehow?

Comment: StackExchange won't let me delete the question. But I find that it clarifies something I hadn't known.